# BlenderGIS shapefile import convert to sphere objects

Tags: objects, add-on, import

I have imported a shapefile of XYZ coordinates into Blender using the BlenderGIS plugin. The result is a cloud of vertex points in space which looks great (see image)[image]
I would like to convert these into shapes (e.g. UV Spheres) ideally scaled to a certain attribute. Does anyone know how this can be done? Is it part of the BlenderGIS plugin or separate? Has anyone come across a python script that can do this?

Comment: I think you could use the [sverchock](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49399/create-an-object-at-each-vector-in-a-list-in-sverchok/49404#49404) plugin for this. Just add a different list for the scale factor input, and I think you are in business.

Comment: In [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67622/935) I give an example using [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) to duplicate an object on the verts of another, you can add in some nodes to adjust the scale for each item.

Comment: Thanks for these replies.  Both of these methods seem to work. I am running into problems however scaling the size of the objects based on a field or attribute.  I know "that [Blender cannot handle attribute data included in dbase file linked to the shapefile.](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/blob/master/README.md)", is there a work around to this other than changing the BlenderGIS import shapefile code?   ( I should note that this is only a problem if i want to maintain the correct spatial reference that BlenderGIS does so well)